# Repeating iOS Notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, unnotificationrequest, unnotificationtrigger

Is there any way to schedule local notification which fires at specific date and the repeats every minute?
Example: user receive first notification at 8:00 AM and then 8:01, 8:02...

Answer (score 0):

To schedule repeated notification you need date components in trigger initialization.

e.g.

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600)
let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second], from: date)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)
```

trigger repeats notification daily

try to setup trigger using only `.second` in date components

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600)
let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: date)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)
```

Comment: This notification fires every minute since time when it was scheduled, but I need notification which repeats only after specific date. I am trying to build alarm clock, maybe you have idea how can i do that.